# when i call myMethod().send() using web3 state vars aren't updated and there is no transaction cost?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

I am calling a method on my contract like so...

```
contractInstance.methods.addSchool(result, web3.utils.fromAscii(req.body.schoolName)).send({from: defaultAccount})
```

The transaction is mined but no state variables are updated. when I look at the transaction details the gas is always 9000 and there is no transaction cost. What am I doing wrong? The method works if I call it from browser solidity.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your contract do in the `addSchool` function? The amount of gas set to 9000 seems to low, try increasing it like this `contractInstance.methods.addSchool(result, web3.utils.fromAscii(req.body.schoolName)).send({from: defaultAccount, gas: 1500000})`.